# How to extract string in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh, ksh

I have file names like `Tarun_Verma_25_02_2016_10_00_10.csv`. How can I extract the string like `25_02_2016_10_00_10` from it in shell script?

It is not confirmed that how many numeric parts there would be after "firstName"_"lastName"

A one-line solution would be preferred.

Comment: What is the format of your filenames ? Do you want all the numbers before the `.`?

Comment: Requests for one-liners are generally frowned on -- if you care about terseness more than correctness, you should be asking on Code Golf, not SO.

Comment: Yes ... i want every thing before "." and after "Tarun_Verma_" ..Please suggest !!

Comment: its not compulsary to have solution in one line....you answers would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ksh93 supports the syntax bash calls extglobs out-of-the-box. Thus, in ksh93, you can do the following:

```
f='Tarun_Verma_25_02_2016_10_00_10.csv'
f=${f##+([![:digit:]])} # trim everything before the first digit
f=${f%%+([![:digit:]])} # trim everything after the last digit
echo "$f"
```

To do the same in bash, you'll want to run the following command first

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Since this uses shell-native string manipulation, it runs much more quickly than invoking an external command (sed, awk, etc) when processing only a single line of input. (When using ksh93 rather than bash, it's quite speedy even for large inputs).

Answer (score 2):

with `sed`

```
$ echo Tarun_Verma_25_02_2016_10_00_10.csv | sed -r 's/[^0-9]*([0-9][^.]*)\..*/\1/'

25_02_2016_10_00_10
```

extract everything between the first digit and dot.

Answer (score 1):

If you want some control over which parts you pick out (assuming the format is always like `<firstname>_<lastname>_<day>_<month>_<year>_<hour>_<minute>_<second>.csv`)  `awk` would be pretty handy

```
 echo "Tarun_Verma_25_02_2016_10_00_10.csv" | awk -F"[_.]" 'BEGIN{OFS="_"}{print $3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8}'
```

Here `awk` splits by both underscore and period, sets the Output Field Seperator to an underscore, and then prints the parts of the file name that you are interested in.

Comment: thanks for answers ..but it is not confirmed that how many parts would be there after "firstName"_"lastName" .....above one won't work :(

Comment: I've added that to the original question to help guide future answers.